# Convert \n\r to string does nothing in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to take a text from my textarea, put in a variable, an change all the linebreaks (\n\r) to "@@".
For some reason it won't work.

Help please, here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HK82q/

```
$("#go").click(function(){
 curtext = $("textarea").val();
 curtext = curtext.replace("\n\r\n","@@");
 alert(curtext);
});
```

Comment: Why do you have `\n\r\n` in your replace condition?

Comment: Apart from that, there _are_ no line breaks in your textarea’s content in your fiddle.

Comment: I have \n\r\n beacuse I want "linebreak + space" = \n\r\n turn into @@

Answer (score 3):

"Line break" can mean one of three things:

- `\r` (carriage return), used by old Mac computers
- `\n` (line feed), used by Linux, Unix, and I think new Macs
- `\r\n` (CRLF), used by Windows

Therefore, you need to handle all three cases. This can be done with multiple `.replace` calls, or a regex:

```
curtext = curtext.replace(/(?=[\r\n])\r?\n?/g,"@@");
```

This regex works by first asserting that there is either a CR or LF ahead, then matching them optionally to allow for all three options. The assertion ensures that "nothing" doesn't match.

Comment: Thanks alot! I think I got my question wrong. I want to change linebreak then empty row (linebreak then space lets say) into @@. and all 2 linebreaks into 1 linebreak. Thanks!

Comment: After the `\n?` in the regex, add `*` (space, asterisk) to also match any spaces that follow it. You can add the same at the start of the regex too (before the `(?=`) to strip spaces that might be at the end of a line.

Answer (score 1):

You're expecting to meet a `\n` followed by `\r`. It's wrong. You should expect either one or the other. Then, regex for `replace` function should be enclosed with `/` not with `"`. It's not a string. The last thing - add the `g` modifier (stands for global - will replace all occurences, not only the first one).

```
curtext = curtext.replace(/[\n\r]/g,"@@");
```

Here's the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HK82q/1/

Comment: Windows uses `\r\n`, so all newlines will become `@@@@`

Comment: Well, having tested your Fiddle, I guess they changed something or maybe IE uses `\n` only... not sure which, but in any case it only has `@@` for each newline. Huh.